# "Denoising" checkbox missing in Blender 2.9

Tags: cycles-render-engine, denoise

In Blender 2.8+, I used to check the "Denoising" checkbox in the View Layer Properties when using Cycles rendering engine but after installing Blender 2.9, I can't find this item anymore:

[image]

Does someone know how I denoise image renders now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denoising has been moved into the "Render Properties" tab under "sampling"

[image: 1]

Comment: That's it, thanks!